# Failing to update single value in a simple/flat observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

If I have a simple list of strings, I can add/remove items and knockout updates the UI, but how can I get an edit/update to work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5M5bL/2/

javascript

```
function myVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.myList = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.editItem = function(data) {
        $( "#dialog-edit" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          title: "Edit " + data,
          buttons: {
            "Save": function() {
                //data("new value");
                //data = "new value";
                // ??? How would I update this item's myList value from here?
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        }).show();
    }
}

var vm = new myVM();
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Ham"));
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Cheese"));
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Egg"));
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Food</th>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: myList">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
            <td><button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.editItem">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
</div>
```

How can I get my editItem/Save function to update the original myList array? At that point, 'data' is just a plain string not an updatable observable

So if I try to update with data("New Value") I get the error 'data' is not a function

Comment: Thanks both of you. hilarudeens second fiddle shows how to solve the problem through knockouts $index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find some of the things in following code,

```
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Ham"));
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Cheese"));
vm.myList.push(ko.observable("Egg"));
```

Here the observable array is holding list of observable. In Knockout, Observable are anonymous functions, all of the observables are need to reuse in future. So you have to make anonymous observable to named observable. So I have changed your code as follows,

```
vm.myList.push({name:ko.observable("Ham")});
vm.myList.push({name:ko.observable("Cheese")});
vm.myList.push({name:ko.observable("Egg")});
```

This will lead to some changes in html as follows,

```
<td data-bind="text: name"></td>
```

Now you can reuse the observable as follows,

```
data.name("wow");
```

Here "data" is object in observable array, and data.name is a observable.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5M5bL/8/

**EDIT** And there is an alternate way. Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/5M5bL/11/

Comment: So it's not possible to do on a 'flat' array? I have to make it an array of objects containing observables?

Comment: @mejobloggs, See my edit. There is no need for extra loop in ViewModel

Comment: Aha that's neat. Wasn't aware of $index. Added brackets and semicolon to make your second fiddle work: http://jsfiddle.net/5M5bL/12/

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function to loop on the array as the parameter is string so you will have to search for it on the array

function myVM() {
    var self = this;

```
self.myList = ko.observableArray([]);

self.editItem = function(data) {
    $( "#dialog-edit" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      title: "Edit " + data,
      buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
           for(var i = 0;i<self.myList().length;i++)
           {
               if(self.myList()[i]() ==data)
               {
                   self.myList()[i]("New Value");
                   break;
               }
           }
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    }).show();
}
```

}

Comment: data("New Value") gives error 'object is not a function'.
'data' from the save function is actually the click event I believe.

And the 'data' from the editItem function is just a plain string